# Problem saving data in a database column with enum data type

Tags: sql, laravel, enums, schema

Have created a Laravel schema and the column has enum data type. By default, it should save Agent in the column which works fine. When a user inserts some data am trying to change it to Agency but when checking on the DB it still remains as Agent:

Kindly assist?

**Database schema**

```
$table->enum('agent_or_agency', array('Agent','Agency'))->default('Agent');
```

**Saving data in the above column from the logic**

```
$data = new Agents();
$data->agent_or_agency =  'Agency';
$data->save();
```

Comment: @Nick Any idea?

Comment: have you added fillabel in your model like protected $fillable = ['agent_or_agency'];

Comment: Is there any other column in your table?